# Can I close an ActiveX combobox placed on an Excel worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I can open the combobox using `object.dropdown` but this isn't a True/False scenario. I'm using this to force the combobox to display the list but it remains on the screen when switching worksheets unless it is manually closed or an item selected. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried programmatically selecting, say, cell A1 on the sheet with the dropdown when switching worksheets? I don't know if it works, just suggesting something here.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that but I have the worksheet locked. But that makes me wonder if I can set the focus to achieve the same thing. I'll report back!

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with is to select the default value when the sheet deactivate event is triggered. The default value is not valid in my application and it tests for it before running the report so this shouldn't cause me any issues.